# Output in XML format in Microsoft Cognitive Service web search API

Tags: r, api, azure-cognitive-services

I m doing a search in the Api of web search  with this URL in R

https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=micropropagacion+empresa&mkt=es-AR&subscription-key= MI KEY "

I am obtaining the info in JSON format , but i need to obtain this in XMl format

Someone knows how can i modify my URL to obtain this info.

Comment: It's called "stop being lazy and Read The F(ine/'ing) Manual": https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-web-search-api We're happy to help, but that doesn't include helping you avoid actually doing SOME work on your own.

Comment: Hi  Marc  I was looking in the manual but i didnt see anything about it.

Comment: Also I wrote to support but they dont have a real response to me

Comment: They seem to be wiser than us.

Comment: @MarcB No need to be rude here - while you can come to the conclusion the API only supports JSON by the fact that all samples in the documentation are using only this format, it's nowhere clearly stated that there is no other option than JSON. In fact, I found this information only by accident while reading through the V2 migration guide linked in my answer below. So I think it's a valid question, considering earlier versions of the API supported XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v5 web search API does only support JSON as a response format. There is a clear statement about this in the V2 migration guide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt707570.aspx):

> Version 5 supports only the JSON response format.

Comment: You're welcome, @SergioCuellar ... please consider marking this as the answer so the question does not continue to appear as unanswered.